# Access UIView with Class Method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have 2 view controllers AViewController and BViewController as an example. I want to add a UI element in the second BViewController from the first AViewController. I thought I would make this happen through the class method but the UIView is not accessable in the BViewController's class method when called from AViewController.

Implementation of BViewController
+(void)addThatButton{
     UIButton *btn = ......
     [self.view addSubview:btn]; //<== ERROR 
     //[BViewController.view addSubview:btn]; //<== ALSO ERROR
}

Implemention of AViewController
[BViewController addThatButton];

Error message I get is "request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union". How to implememnt what I need in the right way or, in other words, how to access BViewController view from the A class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function in BViewController

In BViewController.h

```
UIButton *btnB;

-(void)passButtonFromA:(UIButton *)btn;
```

In BViewController.m

```
-(void)passButtonFromA:(UIButton *)btn{
     btnB = btn;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.view addSubView:btnB];
}
```

In AViewController.m

```
 BViewController *bViewController =[[BViewController alloc]initWithNibName:.. ...]; //allocated bViewController using your nib file
 [bViewController passButtonFromA:btnA];
 [self.navigationViewController pushViewController:bViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Does this method need to be class method instead?

Comment: -(void)passButtonFromA:(UIButton *)btn;

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:  A "+" method is a static method, and "self" refers not to an instance but rather to the class.  Thus self.view is meaningless.

Your basic scheme would work (with a few caveats) if you changed to a "-" method and somehow got the address of your BViewController instance in the AViewController and used that address in the call.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I would make this happen through the class method but the UIView is not accessable in the BViewController's class method when called from AViewController.

That's because there is no `UIView` to access.  A class method runs independently of any instance.  If you want a particular object to be updated, then you need to call one of its instance methods.